# Error: Managed interface that is released can't implement new interfaces (bug?)

Tags: managed-package, error, platform-bug, global-methods, interface

I have a managed package with the following class already in it:

```
global class MyInterfaceClass
{
    global interface InnerInterface {}
    global interface DeepInterface extends InnerInterface {}
}
```

When I edit this class *without making any changes* and save it I get the error in the subject line. The error is pointing to line 4 where the extension is defined.

Has anyone else come across this anomaly? Any suggestions on how to solve it? I have tried editing in Developer Console as well as the web editor both with same outcomes.

Comment: Sounds a bit like a bug for a very specific way of setting two interfaces. You would probably find if `InnerInterface` wasn't defined in the same class as `DeepInterface` it would be fine. There might be some validation mix up that makes it look like the base interface is changing, even though it isn't.

Comment: FWIW I have the same error message with a class that has been released for ages, and modified multiple times since initial release without problems. It doesn't have the same nested interface structure though: it simply implements a bunch of interfaces (Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts and Database.Stateful)